# Converting backslash single quote \' to backslash double quote \" for JSON

Tags: python, json, str-replace

I've got a JSON file that was converted to a string in Python. Somehow along the way the double quotes have gotten replaced with single quotes.

`{\'MyJSON\': {\'Report\': \'1\' ....`

I need to convert my string so that it is in this format instead:

`{\"MyJSON\": {\"Report\": \"1\" ....`

My problem is that using str.replace, I can't figure out how to convert a single quote into a double quote as both quotes are escaped.

My ultimate goal is to be able to put the string into json.loads so that I can pretty print it.

---

Attempts:

```
txt.replace(r"\'", r'\"')
> "{'MyJSON': {'Report': '1'"
```

```
txt.replace("\"", "\'")
> "{'MyJSON': {'Report': '1'"
```

---

If I save my string to a txt file it appears in the preview as:

`{'MyJSON': {'Report': '1' ...`

So I think what I actually need to do is replace ' with "

---

I have decided to use `ast.literal_eval(txt)` which can convert my string to a dictionary. From there, `json.loads(json.dumps(dict))` gets me to JSON

Comment: Sound like you loaded the JSON into a dict, then used `json.dumps(str(the_dict))`. You should just use `json.dumps(the_dict)`, without converting it to a string first.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, my eventual goal is to fix in upstream in the process, but for now I'm stuck with the end result. I think what happened is that the JSON was encrypted into a string.

Comment: Are you sure the string actually contains literal backslash characters? If a string contains a quote, printing it in the REPL will escape single quotes.

Comment: `>>> "foo\"'bar"` displays `'foo"\'bar'`

Comment: @Barmar Great point, I dumped the string into a txt file and the literal backslash character has disappeared. I think what I really need to do is ' -> \"

Comment: However, that will be a problem if there are any literal quotes in the data, since they'll also be converted to `"`, producing invalid JSON. It's hard to automate this.

Comment: Yeah, I'm wondering if it just makes it impossible at some points, like if you have "Fred's House" in your original JSON -- it's going to be hard to get it back in that format

Comment: Exactly. It actually will be double-escaped, but it's hard to write a `str.replace()` to match one and not the other. You can get closer with regexp using negative lookbehinds, but there still may be troublesome cases (like a literal backslash followed by literal quote).

Comment: ```ast.literal_eval``` gets me to a dictionary, which is a lot easier to work with. From there, ```json.loads(json.dumps(dict))``` will get me to JSON

Comment: Of course, should have thought of that. I was fixated on the backslashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of focusing on the backslashes to try to "hack" a json string / dict str into a JSON, a better solution is to take it one step at a time and start by converting my dict string into a dictionary.

```
import ast
txt = ast.literal_eval(txt) # convert my string to a dictionary
txt = json.loads(json.dumps(txt)) # convert my dict to JSON
```

Answer (score 0):

i mean,

```
my_string = "\"\'"
print(my_string.replace("\'", "\""))
```

works perfectly fine

EDIT: i didn't mean use this directly, it was a proof of concept. In mine the replacement was reversed. I have updated this snippet such that it could directly be put into your code. Try it again

Comment: This is doing the opposite replacement from what he wants.

Comment: This will replace all quotes, not just the ones that have backslash before them.

Comment: @Barmar this way simply an example, i can update it to be in the correct replacement, however didn't he want to replace all quotes? I don't think there is ever an occurrence of `\\\"` in his script, which would translate to `\"`